# If $a_k>0\ \forall\ k\in \mathbb{N}\ $ and $r>0,\ $ prove that $\sum\frac{1}{a_k}$ converges $\iff \sum\frac{1}{a_k+r}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

If $a_k > 0\ \forall\ k \in \mathbb{N}\ $ and $r>0,\ $ prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a_k}$ converges $\iff \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a_k+r}$ converges.

$\implies\ $ is easy: $\frac{1}{a_k + r}<\frac{1}{a_k}\ \forall\ k \in \mathbb{N}.$

$\impliedby\ $ is more difficult. I [provide my answer below](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time.), but certainly welcome other answers: there are often simpler solutions as I tend to over-complicate things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use the limit comparison test. Note that, for either series to converge, we must have
$$\frac{1}{a_k}\to 0\Leftrightarrow a_k\to\infty.$$
In particular, for all $N$, there exists some $k_0$ for which $a_k>N$ for all $k>k_0$. We claim that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_k}{a_k+r}=1.$$
Indeed, for any $\epsilon$,
$$\left|1-\frac{a_k}{a_k+r}\right|<\epsilon$$
is equivalent to $a_k>N$ for some $N$, so there exists a $k_0$ for which this holds for all $k>k_0$. By the limit comparison test, the convergences of the two series are equivalent.

Comment: The LCT is something I have seen in passing, but not *really* come across (until now). Interesting.

Comment: @AdamRubinson It's worth noting that your proof is essentially a weaker version -- if you increase the $\frac 12$ in $\frac 1{2a_k}$ up towards $1$, you basically get the limit comparison test.

Comment: You can't replace the $\frac{1}{2a_k}$ in my penultimate line with $\frac{1}{a_k}$ (no such $j$ exists). So I kind of see how my answer kind of relates to the LCT, but not quite. I do think I understand your answer though.

Comment: Oh, do you mean that *by* the LCT: $\sum\frac{1}{2a_k}$ diverges $\iff \sum\frac{1}{a_k}$ diverges $\iff \sum\frac{1}{a_k+r}$ diverges? But that makes my answer looks silly because the LCT bypasses all my working, as you have shown. Surely my answer can be viewed as *avoiding* the LCT.

Comment: @AdamRubinson That's right. What I meant was that you can prove the limit comparison rule as follows: if $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n}=c,$$ then there are some constants $c_1,c_2$ so that $$c_1y_n\leq x_n\leq c_2y_n$$ for large enough $n$, and so $\sum x_n$ converges if and only if $\sum y_n$ does. This is basically what you did, with $c_1=\frac 12$ and $c_2=1$.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying I can re-write both implications, $\impliedby$ and $\implies$ of my proof as a sandwich which is equivalent to the LCT: $\ \exists j \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{2a_k} \leq \frac{1}{a_k+1} \leq \frac{1}{a_k}$ for all $k \geq j$, so by the sandwich theorem/LCT, $\frac{1}{a_k}$ converges $ \iff \frac{1}{a_k+r}$

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

We are trying to prove that, if $r>0,\ $ $\large{\frac{1}{a_k-r}}$ $\ > 0\ \forall\ k \in \mathbb{N}\ $ and $\ \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a_k}\ $ converges then $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a_k-r}\ $ also converges.

I will prove the contrapositive of $\impliedby,\ $ that is, $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a_k}\ $ diverges $\implies\ \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a_k+r}\ $ diverges.

If $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{a_k}\right) \neq 0,\ $ then $\exists\ c>0\ $ such that $\large{\frac{1}{a_k}}$ $ \geq c\ $ for infinitely many $k,\ $ which implies $\large{\frac{1}{a_k+r} \geq \frac{c}{1+rc}}$ $>0\ \forall\ k \in \mathbb{N},\ $ which implies that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a_k+r}\ $ diverges, and we are done. So let's assume for the rest of the proof that $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{a_k}\right) = 0.$

Then $\exists\ j \in \mathbb{N}\ $ such that $a_k \geq r\ \forall\ k \geq j,\ $

\begin{align} \implies\ \frac{1}{2a_k} = \frac{1}{a_k + a_k} \leq \frac{1}{a_k + r}\ \forall k \geq j\\
\\
\implies \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a_k+r} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\frac{1}{a_k+r}+\displaystyle \sum_{k=j}^\infty\frac{1}{a_k+r} > \displaystyle \sum_{k=j}^\infty\frac{1}{a_k+r} \geq \frac{1}{2} 
 \displaystyle \sum_{k=j}^\infty\frac{1}{a_k} = \infty.\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

We should restrict to the case that $a_{k}>0$ for all $k$. Otherwise,
it is possible that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{k}+r}$ converges
but $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{k}}$ is undefined (because $\frac{1}{0}$
is undefined).

Since $\frac{1}{a_{k}+r}\leq\frac{1}{a_{k}},$ we have $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{k}+r}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{k}}$.
It follows that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{k}}$ converges $\Rightarrow$
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{k}+r}$ converges.

Conversely, assume that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{k}+r}$ converges.
In particular, $\frac{1}{a_{k}+r}\rightarrow0$ and hence $a_{k}\rightarrow\infty.$
Now, $\frac{a_{k}+r}{a_{k}}\rightarrow1$, so there exists $K$ such
that $\frac{a_{k}+r}{a_{k}}\leq2$ whenever $k\geq K$. Observe that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=K}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{k}} & = & \sum_{k=K}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{k}+r}\cdot\frac{a_{k}+r}{a_{k}}\\
 & \leq & \sum_{k=K}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{k}+r}\cdot2\\
 & < & \infty.
\end{eqnarray*}
It follows that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_k}$ converges.

Comment: Yes I've edited the question to be $a_k > 0$ rather than $a_k \geq 0.$